# How to set custom url for loading images on page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have set this path for loading images:

```
<img src="{{\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::url($newest->uploaded->where('upf_uploaded_as', 'feature_image')->where('upf_dimension', '200x200')->first()->upf_path)}}" class="card-img-top" alt="">
```

And this is basically going to the URL of the current website domain and open up `storage/upload/1399/10/images/{imagename}`.

But now, I need to specify another URL as a domain. So instead of this:

`http://currentwebsite.com/storage/upload/1399/10/images/PCVS511-5 (1).jpg`

This will load the images:

`http://differentwebsite.com/storage/upload/1399/10/images/PCVS511-5 (1).jpg`

So the path that calls `storage/upload/1399/10/images/{imagename}` is the same. The domain name is just different. But I don't know how to give my custom URL to this.

So if you know, please help me out with this, cause I really need it.

Thanks.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#url-host-customization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create another drive for the storage (found in `config/filesystems.php`), which has the same configuration as the original, but has a different setting for the `url` option:

```
'other_public' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
    'url' => 'http://differentwebsite.com/storage',
    'visibility' => 'public',
],
```

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#url-host-customization)

Comment: You mean at `config/filesystems.php` ?

Comment: @cerealikaeme yes, that would be the one. I'll add it to the answer!